# Django Filtering using distance_lte and Foreign Key

Tags: django, filter, distance, geodjango, django-queryset

I want to use Geodjango to filter using `distance_lte` for a `Point` object composed of latitude and longitude values. Here is how I set up my models:

```
class Point(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Thing(models.Model):
    point = models.ForeignKey(Point)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

I have tried to filter like this, but it has not worked:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Thing, Point
>>> from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
>>> pnt = Point(37.7725205498, -122.408472587)
>>> z = Thing.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt,D(km=5)))
 TypeError: Related Field has invalid lookup: distance_lte
```

How do I do something like this?  :

```
>>> z = Thing.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt,D(km=5)))
             ### or ###
>>> z = Thing.objects.filter(point__(latitude_longitude)__distance_lte=(pnt,D(km=5)))
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Are you subclassing your models from from django.contrib.gis.db? If not, you should.

Comment: I just realized that I imported both `django.db.models` and `django.contrib.gis.db.models`. However, after removing the `django.db.models` import I still get the same result from this query: `z = Thing.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt,D(km=5)))
 TypeError: Related Field has invalid lookup: distance_lte`. Is there anything else that I could be missing? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: And you've reset all your models in the DB after doing that?

Comment: I tried to run a schemamigration using South, but it said that nothing has changed. Do I need to dump and recreate the db?

Comment: I would if it's not onerous. Just to eliminate the possibility. Also, is your Point model subclassing the geo models? That model needs to.

Comment: use the python manage.py reset <app> if you still have it in your Django version, it was deprecated after 1.5 I believe.

Comment: Thanks I'll just delete the db because I read that using `reset` with South can sometimes cause problems. But I guess what you're telling me is that a query like `Thing.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt,D(km=5)))` should not return `TypeError: Related Field has invalid lookup: distance_lte`, if I'm not mistaken? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Indeed - the distance_lte is a geodjango manager filter, they need to act on instances of the gis models. So the Point model needs to be one to work.

Comment: Hmmm I did all of that but still getting the same error. I can't figure out why the query won't work.. Anything else I may be missing?

Comment: Any reason you are not using a [PointField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.PointField)? [The distance queries introduction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries) suggests to me you should be.

Comment: @Steven I'm not using a PointField because I wanted to use latitude and longitude explicitly for other reasons. However, I am creating a `Point` object as shown above, so I thought I'd be in the clear and able to query using distance_lte. Thanks for any ideas though!

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary but not sufficient to use the GeoManager.  The database must be told that a field contains spatial data (including the co-ordinate system to use) so it can interpret that data at query time, index it appropriately, etc..  For PostGIS it does this by adding these columns via the [AddGeometryColumn stored procedure](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/creation.py#L39).  Your code is only creating float fields in the database.

Therefore your easiest approach is to add a [PointField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield), either to your `Point` model in which case your lookups may look more like `point__point__distance_lte` or directly to the `Thing` model in place of the ForeignKey field (potentially renaming this field instead if you still want to store lat/long separately).

Comment: Thanks for the information @Steven. If I just use `PointField`, is there a way to unpack the latitude and longitude values to use them individually?

Comment: @NickB I believe you can retrieve them from the field [as described here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#geometries-are-pythonic).  You might also be able to use point.x and point.y for longitude and latitude respectively.